# Entity Framework one-to-many won't update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I'm having an issue, regarding Entity Framework and one-to-many relationship.
I am also using the Repository Pattern.
I have this classes and relations:

```
public class Field {
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
public class Value {
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in an other class I want to add a Value to a Field. I have the new object Value and the Id of the Field I want to add it to.

```
using (OContext context = new OContext())
{
    var rField = new Repository<Field>(context);
    var rValue = new Repository<Value>(context);
    var field = (Field)r.Get(fieldId);
    rValue.Add(value);
    field.Values.Add(value);
    rField.Update(field);
}
```

In the database the value is correctly added but the FieldId reference is NULL even if I update the Field like that. (to the Values list)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you sure this code compiles?